# String cannot be assigned in the class constructor

Tags: java

I have two classes,

`SymString.java`

```java
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class SymString {
    private String str;
    private int temp = 0, flag = 0;

    public SymString(String paraStr) {
        str = paraStr;
    }

    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer(str);

    public int getLength() {
        return (strBuffer.length());
    }

    public boolean isSymStr() {
        for (temp = 0; temp <= getLength(); temp++) {
            if (strBuffer.charAt(temp) == strBuffer.charAt(getLength() - (temp + 1))) {
                flag++;
            }
        }
        if (flag == getLength()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isSymStr2() {
        if (strBuffer.reverse().equals(strBuffer)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

`TestSymStr.java`

```java
class TestSymStr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SymString Test1 = new SymString("lmfao let's try it out.");
        System.out.println("Is the string symmetric?");
        System.out.println(Test1.isSymStr2());
        System.out.println(Test1.isSymStr());
    }

}
```

and it just throws the exception, seems like the `str` has not be assigned. Why?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:139)
    at SymString.<init>(SymString.java:13)
    at TestSymStr.main(TestSymStr.java:5)
```

Comment: `StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer(str);` **is** being executed!  But it executes before the body of the constructor, and `str` doesn't get it's (non-null) value  until the the constructor executes.  So you basically  end up with `new StringBuffer(null)` and KABOOM!  Solution: move the initialization of `strBuffer` from the declaration into the constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by "overflow" @Goion?  What can overflow here?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Nvm. I though he is declaring the object of class itself.

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code  `private String str;` initializes the String with `null`. When you call the constructor the it tries to initialize the `StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer(str);` as well. Where the constructor of `StringBuffer` is called. Which has code like below:

```
/**
     * Constructs a string buffer initialized to the contents of the
     * specified string. The initial capacity of the string buffer is
     * {@code 16} plus the length of the string argument.
     *
     * @param   str   the initial contents of the buffer.
     */
    public StringBuffer(String str) {
        super(str.length() + 16);
        append(str);
    }
```

Because before executing the constructor code the Class variables are initialized. So till here `str` is `null`, which is causing this `NullPointerException`. So you can achieve it create `strBuffer` using defaulr constructor and append the `str` inside the constructor as below.

```
    private String str;
    private int temp = 0, flag = 0;
    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    public SymString(String paraStr) {
        str = paraStr;
        strBuffer.append(str);
    }


    public int getLength() {
        return (strBuffer.length());
    }
```

But even after that you code will break because in `isSymStr()` method you are iterating from **0 index to the length**, while you need to iterate till **length -1** as below.

```
public boolean isSymStr() {
        for (temp = 0; temp < getLength(); temp++) {
            if (strBuffer.charAt(temp) == strBuffer.charAt(getLength() - (temp + 1))) {
                flag++;
            }
        }
        if (flag == getLength()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```